# Postgres trgm GIN index not used for query inside function

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have a function which executes a dynamic query with variables passed to it.

I have expression indexes defined, but they are not being used. An average query is taking about 7 seconds. If I do:

```
 SET enable_seqscan=f;
```

the same query takes just 1 second. How can I make Postgres use the indexes?

Here is my function:

```
--Usage: select * from scored_search('hinton', 0.5, 1.0, 10000);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION scored_search(
vn character varying(500), tn real, wn real, lim integer 
) RETURNS SETOF contact_index_with_score AS 
$func$
DECLARE
  nlim integer := lim/4;
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE
  'SELECT *,
      (CASE gn > $2 WHEN true THEN gn ELSE 0 END) * $3
    AS score
  FROM (
    SELECT *,
    /* Word sim parameters ordered so name token can match multi-token name */
      greatest(multi_word_similarity(coalesce($1,''''), coalesce(contact_name1,'''')),
               multi_word_similarity(coalesce($1,''''), coalesce(contact_name2,'''')),
               multi_word_similarity(coalesce($1,''''), coalesce(contact_name3,'''')),
               multi_word_similarity(coalesce($1,''''), coalesce(contact_name4,'''')),
               multi_word_similarity(coalesce($1,''''), coalesce(contact_name5,''''))) AS gn
    FROM (
      (SELECT * FROM contact_search_index WHERE $1 <%
        normalize_string(coalesce(contact_name1,'''') || '' '' ||
         coalesce(contact_name2,'''') || '' '' ||
         coalesce(contact_name3,'''') || '' '' ||
         coalesce(contact_name4,'''') || '' '' ||
         coalesce(contact_name5,'''')) COLLATE "default" LIMIT $13)
    ) AS filtered_contact_index
  ) AS max_similarities
  ORDER BY score DESC'
USING 
  vn, tn, wn, nlim;
END
$func$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Here is my index definition:

```
CREATE INDEX contact_search_name_trgm_idx on contact_search_index 
USING GIN((
  normalize_string(coalesce(contact_name1, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce(contact_name2, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce(contact_name3, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce(contact_name4, '') || ' ' ||
  coalesce(contact_name5, '')) 
) COLLATE "default" gin_trgm_ops);
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this. I am seeing similar problems.